# Converting html to image using java on google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications

I was trying to convert html to image using Google's API HtmlImageGenerator. But when I upload the code on Google app engine it blocks many classes like JLabel,ImageIO,JeditorPane,Dimension2D etc. So what java API can I use on google app engine to save a html page as image file?

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Conversion API.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/conversion/)